# Heroku Application Error python flask

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I'm trying to make production ready.
Have my own domain in future and make calls for stripe.
However I'm having issue deploying my app.

'geeni.py'

```
class ChargeUser(Resource):
    def post(self):
        jsonData = request.get_json(force=True)
        stripeid = jsonData['stripeid_customer']
        currency = jsonData['currency']
        amount = jsonData['amount']
        apiKey = jsonData['api_key']
        try:
            stripe.Charge.create(amount = amount, source=stripeid, currency=currency)
            return jsonify({'Msg':'Charged!'})
        except:
            raise

api.add_resource(ChargeUser,'/')
if __name__ == "__main__":
    port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Under my ProcFile I have
following stuff

```
"web gunicorn geeni:app"
```

So I call

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Instantly throws me this error:

```
    2016-11-04T09:07:19.592920+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-11-04T09:07:20.540914+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-11-04 09:07:20 [3] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2016-11-04T09:07:20.541241+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-11-04 09:07:20 [7] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7)
2016-11-04T09:07:20.752145+00:00 app[web.1]: 2016-11-04 09:07:20 [3] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2016-11-04T09:07:20.932424+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2016-11-04T09:07:46.047825+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-11-04T09:07:46.047990+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-11-04T09:07:46.144820+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-11-04T09:07:46.158902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-11-04T09:07:48.965583+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=geeni-api.herokuapp.com request_id=0c8f07bb-0d78-4518-92b0-247baff498d6 fwd="24.130.184.126" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-11-04T09:07:51.924182+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=geeni-api.herokuapp.com request_id=72547341-f293-4b7a-acbf-fb560b7e4827 fwd="24.130.184.126" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-11-04T09:07:52.690127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=geeni-api.herokuapp.com request_id=7fc5635a-4f8d-4922-b200-7158defebbf7 fwd="24.130.184.126" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

My app file looks something like this

```
geeniHeroku/
   ProcFile
   geeni.py
   requirements.txt
```

What am I doing wrong? I've also done everything such as git init and all the steps you are required to do.
I think the error has to do with my ProcFile content  `web gunicorn geeni:app`

Here's the contents of requirements.txt

```
Flask==0.10.1
Flask_RESTful==0.2.12
itsdangerous==0.24
passlib==1.6.5
requests==2.11.1
stripe==1.27.1
```

Comment: Any additional error lines in the logs? Also, what's the content of your `requirements.txt`?

Comment: @DavidB. Added the contents of requirements.txt

Comment: Right, so `gunicorn` isn't in that file. What if you add it with the relevant version?

Comment: What do you mean? Does gunicorn need to be in requirements.txt? If so could you give me an example?

Comment: Yes it does as described in https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn. So you would add a line: `gunicorn==0.14.2` (with the version of gunicorn you want to use)

Comment: @DavidB. You're right. I was using one of the libraries to get requirements.txt since pip freeze installed a lot of other modules I didn't need. That must've initated the error as I jsut see in logs. Also. Is there a way to get it right for requirements.txt. The method I'm using right now doesn't grab all my models.

Comment: I also use `pip freeze` so not sure what else to recommend there.

Comment: pip freeze gives me about 100 extra modules that I do not need and half of them don't even install right.

Comment: OK. Something else to look into then. Aside from that, is your error gone now and is the application running?

Comment: @DavidB. I get a new error. I've updated the thread!

Comment: I think it has to do with my ProcFile? `web gunicorn geeni:app` that part?

Comment: ...Shouldn't be. An answer has been added below, so does that help?

Comment: It doesn't work still..

Answer (score 4):

Add gunicorn== 19.9.0 to requirements.txt

Comment: Please elaborate what this does and why it answers the question.

Comment: @JJJ it is one of the main requirements to deploy python app to heroku [link](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#adding-gunicorn-to-your-application)

Answer (score 3):

Try to restart heroku:

```
heroku restart
```

If it isn't work, you can try to let heroku to set the IP and port for you, simplely use this:
geeni.py

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And here is [a Flask template for Heroku](https://github.com/zachwill/flask_heroku).

Comment: Maybe you can try to restart all dynos (in heroku dashboard, click the `More` button aside the `Open App` button) or add a favicon in your static directory (link it in your `base.html`).

Comment: I do not have any templates or static folder.

Comment: I've litterarly tried all the things you said. I still end up with Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch

Answer (score 0):

you're setting up a custom port and you shouldn't do that when deploying to Heroku